# How to end _beginthreadex()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

Inside my desktop application I have created a simple thread by using _beginthreadex(...). I wonder what happens if my application will be closed (without explicitly closing the thread)? Will all resources inside the thread be cleared automatically? I have doubts.
So I like to end the thread when my application will be closed. I wonder what would be the best practise? 
Using _endthreadex is only possible inside(!) the thread and something like TerminateThread(...) does not seems to work (infinite loop). Do you have some advices?

Answer (score 1):

When main exits your other threads will be destroyed.

It's best to have main wait on your other threads, using their handles, and send them a message (using an event, perhaps) to signal them to exit. Main can then signal the event and wait for the other threads to complete what they were doing and exit cleanly. Of course this requires that the threads check the event periodically to see if they need to exit.

Answer (score 0):

When the main thread exits, the app and all of its resources are cleaned up. This will include other threads and their resources.

Also, post the code you have for `TerminateThread`, because it works.

Answer (score 0):

The tidiest way is to send your thread(s) a message (or otherwise indicate via an event) that the tread should terminate and allow it to free its resources and exit its entry point function.

Answer (score 0):

To close the thread, you need to call CloseHandle() with the handle returned by _beginthreadex.

The thread is part of the process, so when the process terminates it will take the thread with it and the operating system will resume ownership of everything the two own, so all the resources will be released.

Bear in mind that if you have not forewarned the thread that the-end-is-nigh, it may be in the middle of some work when it ends. If it is in the middle of using any system or external resources, they will be released but may be in a funky state (e.g. a file may be partially written, etc).

See also http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreading_win32A.php

Note: Using CloseHandle() is only for _beginthreadex and not if you are using _beginthread. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @MSalters Yes, when using _beginthread and _endthread: `_endthread automatically closes the thread handle (whereas _endthreadex does not). Therefore, when using _beginthread and _endthread, do not explicitly close the thread handle by calling the Win32 CloseHandle API. This behavior differs from the Win32 ExitThread API.` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.90).aspx) OP said, explicitly, '_beginthreadex'.

Comment: Hmm, that MSDN article is inconsistent. It lists the 4 points where `_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` differ, and the need to call `CloseHandle` is not among them. Luckily Visual Studio ships with the CRT source, `threadex.c` indeed does not contain a call to `CloseHandle`.